# Build custom group headers and footers not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

The json formatting code provided by Microsoft at this page: [List layout customizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) under "Build custom group headers and footers" doesn't seem to work.

If I remove the nested if(s) I manage to get the background color on 1 value, but I still can't manage to get a picture.

If I put the nested if I get a JSON error "unexpected end of string":

[image]

I've tried many things without success. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Are you copying the JSON from documentation as is or did you make any changes to the JSON? Please edit your original question and provide the current JSON you are using in case if you have modified it.

Comment: As the documentation saids `The JSON below contains line breaks. These have been added to improve the readability of the code.` so lines 18 to 23 must be on the same line.

Comment: Can you share your JSON in the form of code which will help me to test your JSON to find out the problem. Please be careful not to disclose your private information.